# SQL LIKE using variable from user as a search

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask, sql-like

I'm trying to make a search functionality to output all available books based on author typed in a form (I'm using sqlite)

I'd like to use LIKE function.

The piece of code I'm using is as follows:

```
# User reached route via POST (submitting the form)
else:
    query = request.form.get("query")

# Ensure symbol is not blank
if not query:
    return apology("you haven't typed anything!", 400)

# A list querying available books by a similar author
books = db.execute("SELECT author, title, genre, id FROM books WHERE booked = 0 AND author LIKE '%' + :query + '%'",
                  query = query)
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.
No errors are found, but when I try to print out books, it returns always empty, even if I type in the exact author name.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `LIKE :query` with `query='%'+query+'%'`

Comment: SQLite's concatenation operator is `||` and not `+`.